# How can cgroup.subtree_control be populated in Docker's private cgroup namespace?

Tags: docker, cgroups, docker-compose

For cgroupv2, by default Docker uses a private namespace for cgroups. This is controlled by the `--cgroupns` flag for `docker run` and the `default-cgroupns-mode` daemon option. I need to create child cgroups within the container, but **the problem is that the root cgroup within the container has an empty `cgroup.subtree_control`!** I can't populate this within the container, since by the time the container is running, this root cgroup already has processes in it. Attempting to do so results in a "device or resource busy" error.

---

`--cgroupns host` would be a workaround, but it's just that — a workaround; it doesn't use the private namespace, which I would like to keep if possible. A further problem is that there's currently [no way](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/issues/148) to set this from a compose file.

---

I looked into `--cgroup-parent`, which *can* be set via a compose file. However, I don't really understand this setting. I created a cgroup on the host, wrote to `subtree_control`, and then tried to start a container using that cgroup as the parent. I received this error, which I didn't understand:

> error response from daemon: cgroup-parent for systemd cgroup should be a valid slice named as "xxx.slice"

I thought what this setting would do is change the "current cgroups directories" in the context of the following quote from the `cgroup_namespaces` manpage:

> When a process creates a new cgroup namespace using clone(2) or unshare(2) with the CLONE_NEWCGROUP flag, its current cgroups directories become the cgroup root directories of the new namespace.

In any case, it is cumbersome to require a cgroup to be manually provisioned on the host before starting the container. What alternatives do I have to ensure `cgroup.subtree_control` in the container has the controllers I need enabled?

Comment: It turns out that for `cgroup-parent` I just had to append `.slice` to the cgroup's name. This solves the immediate error but not the main problem. The container's cgroup does get created within the parent I configured, but that child cgroup still has an empty `subtree_control` rather than inheriting it from its parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a child cgroup in the container, move every PID in `/sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.procs` to the child, and then `/sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.subtree_control` can be written to without any "device or resource busy" error.

Comment: would you please explain your solution? How we can create a new child cgroup?

Comment: @MostafaGhadimi To create a child cgroup, create a new directory e.g. `mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/mychildgroup`.

Comment: Thank you @bgfvdu3w